# Trying to overload an assignment operator on a class.

Tags: c++

HOMEWORK

Below is the code I have created for everything regarding my homework. I am stuck on this last part of the assignment.

Assignment: 
The following is the code he has given us to test our work against.

```
int main()
{
   roman r1 = 1234;
   roman r2 = "DLXVII"; // 567
   roman r3 = r1 + r2;

   cout << r1 << " + " << r2 << " = " << r3;

   cin.get();
}

Produces the following output:

MCCXXXIV + DLXVII = MDCCCI
```

The following is the code I have written.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class roman {
public:
    string numR;
    int numI;

    string romanConversion(int input) {
        string m[] = { "", "M", "MM", "MMM" };
        string c[] = { "", "C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D",
                        "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM" };
        string x[] = { "", "X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L",
                        "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC" };
        string i[] = { "", "I", "II", "III", "VI", "V",
                        "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX" };

        string thousands = m[input / 1000];
        string hundreds = c[(input % 1000) / 100];
        string tens = x[(input % 100) / 10];
        string ones = i[input % 10];

        string answer = thousands + hundreds + tens + ones;
        return answer;
    }
    int value(char r)
    {
        if (r == 'I')
            return 1;
        if (r == 'V')
            return 5;
        if (r == 'X')
            return 10;
        if (r == 'L')
            return 50;
        if (r == 'C')
            return 100;
        if (r == 'D')
            return 500;
        if (r == 'M')
            return 1000;

        return -1;
    }
    int romanToDecimal(string &str)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++)
        {
            int s1 = value(str[i]);

            if (i + 1 < str.length())
            {
                int s2 = value(str[i + 1]);
                if (s1 >= s2)
                {
                    result = result + s1;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = result + s2 - s1;
                    i++; 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = result + s1;
                i++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};

int main() {
    roman test = roman();
    int input = 3999;
    cout << test.romanConversion(input) << endl;
    string roman = "MMMCMXCIX";
    cout << test.romanToDecimal(roman) << endl;
    cin.get();


}
```

We have been working for the better part of the last hour on the last piece of the assignment which is overloading the assignment operator, so we can directly assign both integers, and "roman numerals" and then perform equations on them etc.

We have tried a couple different methods of trying to overload the = method, but encountering an error when submitting a "string" 
Which is "no suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char" to roman.

Any guidance would be great on creating an assignment operator.

Comment: You don't have to overload assignment, you have to overload addition operator. Hint: And how do you expect to overload it without any special function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an interesting assignment.  The compiler is displeased by the fact that you don't have constructors for your roman class that accept integers and character arrays, that it doesn't know how to add two objects of type 'roman' together, and that it doesn't know how to output an object of type roman.  Check the inserted code below and see the places I wrote // you fill in stuff here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class roman {
public:
    string numR;
    int numI;

    roman(int)
    {
       // you fill in stuff here
    }
    roman(const char *)
    {
       // you fill in stuff here
    }

    roman operator+(const roman &rhs)
    {
       // you fill in stuff here
    }

    string romanConversion(int input) {
        string m[] = { "", "M", "MM", "MMM" };
        string c[] = { "", "C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D",
                        "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM" };
        string x[] = { "", "X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L",
                        "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC" };
        string i[] = { "", "I", "II", "III", "VI", "V",
                        "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX" };

        string thousands = m[input / 1000];
        string hundreds = c[(input % 1000) / 100];
        string tens = x[(input % 100) / 10];
        string ones = i[input % 10];

        string answer = thousands + hundreds + tens + ones;
        return answer;
    }
    int value(char r)
    {
        if (r == 'I')
            return 1;
        if (r == 'V')
            return 5;
        if (r == 'X')
            return 10;
        if (r == 'L')
            return 50;
        if (r == 'C')
            return 100;
        if (r == 'D')
            return 500;
        if (r == 'M')
            return 1000;

        return -1;
    }
    int romanToDecimal(string &str)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++)
        {
            int s1 = value(str[i]);

            if (i + 1 < str.length())
            {
                int s2 = value(str[i + 1]);
                if (s1 >= s2)
                {
                    result = result + s1;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = result + s2 - s1;
                    i++; 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = result + s1;
                i++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const roman &)
{
   // you fill in stuff here
   return os;
}

int main()
{
   roman r1 = 1234;
   roman r2 = "DLXVII"; // 567
   roman r3 = r1 + r2;

   cout << r1 << " + " << r2 << " = " << r3;

   cin.get();
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! We got it working after too many hours of head -> desking